# How do I check if my array has repeated values inside it?

Tags: c#, arrays, repeat

So here is my array.

```
double[] testArray = new double[10];
// will generate a random numbers from 1-20, too lazy to write the code
```

I want to make a search loop to check if any values are being repeated. How do I do that?

I would prefer not to use any special built-in methods since this is a small array.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could do this with a little Linq:

```
if (testArray.Length != testArray.Distinct().Count())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains duplicates");
}
```

The [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) extension method removes any duplicates, and [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) gets the size of the result set. If they differ at all, then there are some duplicates in the list.

Alternatively, here's more complicated query, but it may be a bit more efficient:

```
if (testArray.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains duplicates");
}
```

The [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will group any identical elements together, and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return `true` if any of the groups has more than one element.

Both of the above solutions work by utilizing a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx), but you can use one directly like this:

```
if (!testArray.All(new HashSet<double>().Add))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains duplicates");
}
```

Or if you prefer a solution that doesn't rely on Linq at all:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<double>();
foreach(var x in testArray) 
{
    if (!hashSet.Add(x)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contains duplicates");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks. What is Distinct().Count() supposed to do in general?

Comment: Oh I see. So if I ONLY want to check for duplicates then I just remove the Distinct() right? And the Count() method means how many times it got duplicated as in size of result set?

Comment: @Mike no `Count` will return the number of items in the set, i.e. `testArray.Length == testArray.Count()`. To get the number of duplicates, you can just subtract the two, i.e. `testArray.Length - testArray.Distinct().Count()`

Comment: ok thanks the second one worked well enough for checking if there is a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 3):

use a hashset to add members to, then check if there a previous occurrence of current member

```
public bool ContainsDuplicate(double[] nums) 
{
            int size = nums.Length;
            HashSet<double> set1 = new HashSet<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (set1.Contains(nums[i]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    set1.Add(nums[i]);
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With (OP) 10 random doubles quite fast.
The chance of a repeat: ~0.000002 %.

```
static bool repeat(double[] a)
{
    return
        a[0] == a[1] || a[0] == a[2] || a[0] == a[3] || a[0] == a[4] ||
        a[0] == a[5] || a[0] == a[6] || a[0] == a[7] || a[0] == a[8] ||
        a[0] == a[9] || a[1] == a[2] || a[1] == a[3] || a[1] == a[4] ||
        a[1] == a[5] || a[1] == a[6] || a[1] == a[7] || a[1] == a[8] ||
        a[1] == a[9] || a[2] == a[3] || a[2] == a[4] || a[2] == a[5] ||
        a[2] == a[6] || a[2] == a[7] || a[2] == a[8] || a[2] == a[9] ||
        a[3] == a[4] || a[3] == a[5] || a[3] == a[6] || a[3] == a[7] ||
        a[3] == a[8] || a[3] == a[9] || a[4] == a[5] || a[4] == a[6] ||
        a[4] == a[7] || a[4] == a[8] || a[4] == a[9] || a[5] == a[6] ||
        a[5] == a[7] || a[5] == a[8] || a[5] == a[9] || a[6] == a[7] ||
        a[6] == a[8] || a[6] == a[9] || a[7] == a[8] || a[7] == a[9] ||
        a[8] == a[9];
}
```

More general, with 10 numbers ~2 times slower than above,
but ~7 times faster than the hashset approach.

```
static bool repeat(double[] a)
{
    int k = a.Length - 1;
    if (k < 70)
    {
        double aj;
        for (int i = 0, j; i < k; )
        {
            for (aj = a[k--], j = k; j >= i; j--)
                if (aj == a[j]) return true;
            for (aj = a[i++], j = i; j <= k; j++)
                if (aj == a[j]) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    var h = new HashSet<double>();
    while (k >= 0) if (!h.Add(a[k--])) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Two lines (slow with a repeat ;)

```
static bool repeat(double[] a)
{ return (new HashSet<double>(a).Count < a.Length); }
```

Answer (score 2):

take look at my implementation its `generic` and `efficient`

```
public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(IList<T> items)
    {
        Dictionary<T, bool> map = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (map.ContainsKey(items[i]))
            {
                return true; // has duplicates
            }
            map.Add(items[i], true);
        }
        return false; // no duplicates
    }
```

here are some calls

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
Utility.HasDuplicates(strings)// this will return false

int[] items=new []{1,2,3,1};
Utility.HasDuplicates(items)// this will return true
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it slighty to use `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`. I also made it into an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
bool CheckUniqueness(double[] values)
{
    var uniqueValues = new HashSet<double>();
    foreach (double d in values)
    {
        if(uniqueValues.Contains(d))
        {
            return false;
        }
        uniqueValues.Add(d);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We must initialize `j` from `i` on the first loop and add one(i+1) because we want to compare first loop value with the next value of same array.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,1,4,2,5,4};

//create one loop for arr values
for (int i = 0;  i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    //create nested loop for compare current values with actual value of arr
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {

        //and here we put our condition
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is O(n^2) takes too long , not efficient method

Answer (score 0):

Generic extension method :

```
public static bool HasDuplicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(source));

    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
        if (!set.Add(item))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};



        Console.WriteLine(AnyDuplicate(nums));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if there is at least a duplicate in the array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static bool AnyDuplicate(int[] numbers)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                {
                    return true; 
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
```